# Reason for java.io.IOEXception at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.file.Protocol.delete(+76) exception?

Tags: java-me, midp, jsr75

I got above exception while using File Connection in J2ME MIDP2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using file connection in my application. I opened the file using FileConnection and forgot to close it. Because I second time open the same file without closing the file at previous time, it is raising Exception like this. I solved it, it's working good.